# MVVM Light message being received rarely, otherwise never received

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, messaging, dispatcher, wpf-4.5

I am having a strange issue with MVVM Light messaging.  I am using it through my application and it has worked fine.  I am now having a problem where my message is received roughly 10% of the time I try to send it.  I'm assuming it gets shot off in to oblivion the other 90% of the time and I receive no errors and my application goes on as if nothing happened.

What I have is a context menu in a view that has a collection of statuses.  Each user has a status and you can change it via this context menu.  Every time the status changes I need to broadcast a message to another view model.  This is the message that fails.  Here is some code, feel free to ask me more questions if this is not clear enough for you.

This is located in my constructor, fired from a context menu item click:

```
this.UpdateUserStatus = new RelayCommand<UserStatusVM>(x =>
    DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
        {
            UpdateStatus(x);
        }));
```

UpdateStatus method from relay command:

```
private void UpdateStatus(UserStatusVM status)
{
    var userStatusEventId = _userService.CreateUserEvent(status.Id, CurrentUser.Id);

    //This returns a business object that I would like to send
    //over the wire to the other view model
    var userEvent = _userService.GetUserEvent(userStatusEventId);

    if (userEvent != null)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send<UserEvent>(userEvent, "Broadcast");
    }

    //These fire off a collection changed event
    CurrentUser.StatusId = status.Id;
    CurrentUser.Status = status.Name;
    CurrentUser.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    CurrentUser.IsOnDuty = UserStatuses.IsOnDuty(status.Id);
}
```

and the message reception in the other view model:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<UserEvent>(this, "Broadcast", (userEvent) =>
    {
        proxy.Invoke("NewUserEvent", userEvent);
    });
```

Comment: are you sure that userEvent is not null, put a Break point and check whether the message is really sent !

Comment: Just to be clear, I have inserted breakpoints everyone in the workflow.  The userEvent object is != null.  All of the variables that come after the call, on CurrentUser, are also called.  The message is simply disappearing.

Comment: and are you also sure that the other View Model is created when you send a message to it ?

Comment: Yes, and just to be absolutely sure I loaded all the view models automatically in the locator.